# Kerning information from iOS fonts

Tags: ios, opengl-es, fonts, kerning

I have been using bitmap fonts with OpenGL.  Its a basic scheme that uses kerning information and does para layout.  I would like to know if I can get kerning information of fonts through CoreText, so that I can continue using OpenGL for my text rendering.   It appears that in CoreText you can specify a string, gets its glyphs and the advances for the glyphs.  Then I imagine one can back calculate the glyphs for specific kernings. But what I would like is all the kerning pairs.
The brute force would be to create a (really long) string of all possible character pairs, which would be more than a mile long, and then have the advances from CoreText and back calculate the kerning information.  But if there were a direct way to get kerning that would less messy, I would like that.  I know on Windows you can do this, but I was hoping something similar were available in CoreText or Quartz.

Comment: if you use core text it will handle spacing between letters/words and wrap.  I did a console with core text http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14921476/core-text-view-memory-leak it prints a line at a time out and i had to handle spacing between lines and came up with some jury rigged formula base on font height to prevent crashes. this isn't an exact answer(that's why this is just a comment) but i hadn't seen you get any responses.

Comment: Thanks the code is useful for reference.  But I would like to keep control on doing the layout myself as I have my own fonts too.  And CoreText layout won't port.  So I need to know everything that CoreText knows that allows it to do the layout on words and lines.  So mostly what I need is char widths and kerning.  The font height I have already as you did too.  I am experimenting and if I find a brute force to do this I will publish it.